# a problem on a special root of $x^{11}-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have came across the following problem

if $\alpha$ be a special root of the equation $x^{11}-1=0$ , then prove that  $$(\alpha+1)(\alpha^2+1)......(\alpha^{10}+1)=1$$

---

totally stuck on it. how to solve this.please help me somebody.

Comment: What does "special root" mean?

Comment: i guess other than $1$

Comment: special roots means -" it is not a root of the equation $x^k-1$ where $k<11$"

Comment: Since $11$ is prime, in this case $x=1$ is the only root which is not special.

Comment: The usual name for such a root is a *primitive* $11$-th root of unity, I guess.

Answer (score 12):

1. If $\alpha$ is a 'special root', in this case meaning that $\alpha\ne 1$, then using $\alpha^{11}-1=0$, prove that $\alpha^n$ is also a special root of this equation for all $n=1,2,..,10$.
2. Considering these $11$ (distinct!) roots, conclude that the polynomial $f(x)=x^{11}-1$ factors as $f(x)=(x-1)(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)\ldots(x-\alpha^{10})$.
3. Substitue $x=-1$ on both sides.